# Read access violation while removing the last element in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, access-violation, doubly-linked-list

I got an exception in `pop_back()` method for my doubly linked list:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->tail_ was nullptr.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Code for adding a new node and setting the pointers

```
  void push_front(const T& data) {
    //make a node
    Node* nn = new Node(data, head_);
    if (head_ != nullptr) {
        head_->prev_ = nn;
    }
    else {
        tail_ = nn;
    }
    head_ = nn;

}
// Runtime: Linear
void push_back(const T& data) {
    Node* nn = new Node(data);
    if (head_!=nullptr) {
        tail_->next_ = nn;
    }
    else {
        head_ = nn;
    }
    tail_ = nn;
}
```

Code for the delete node:

```
void Sentinel<T>::pop_back() {
    if (head_) { // if list is not empty
        if (head_ != tail_) { // if there is more than one node
            tail_ = tail_->prev_;
            delete tail_->next_; //error is here 
            tail_->next_ = nullptr;
        }
        else {
            delete tail_;
            head_ = tail_ = nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment of the function call the linked list contains `1 0 0 0 3 4`.

Please advice how to fix this code (preferably without the exception handler).

Comment: It sounds like there is a bug in your function that inserts items in the linked list. You need to fix that function.

Comment: Isn't it legal to delete a null pointer? What compiler are you using btw

Comment: @PasserBy Yes, but dereferencing it is not: `tail_ = tail_->prev_;`

Comment: Visual Studio 2015

Comment: @melpomene Oh right, I'm blind. Thought it was `tail_->next` that is a null pointer for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The error appears in this function but the bug is elsewhere.
You get this error on `delete tail_->next` which means that this pointer is pointing to `nullptr`.

The problem is probably in your insert method. The inserted node is not pointing to the previous element.

My advice is to debug your insert method and check if the pointers are set correctly.

Comment: i have attached the functions adding the new nodes above. I can not find a bug in the insertion method. It looks good to me. Please let me know if you notice anything that could be wrong. Thanks